# Super small Vue button

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm learning Vue, and even with the simplest examples there is something wrong. For example, buttons. I have a defined component, myButton, responds to clicks, but it doesn't look like it should, is super small and dont have any label. What am I doing wrong?

[image: mybuttons]

Part of index.js:

```
Vue.component('mybutton', {
props: {
    buttonLabel: String,
},
template: '<button @click="onClick()" class="btn">{{ buttonLabel }}</button>',
methods: {
    onClick(){
        console.log('Click');
    }
  },
})
```

Part of index.html:

```
<div id="app">
  <mybutton text="From Vue"></mybutton>
  <button class="btn">Test</button>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

And CSS:

```
.btn {
display: inline-block;
background: #000;
color: #fff;
border: none;
padding: 10px,20px;
border-radius: 5px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 15px;
font-family: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your prop is called `buttonLabel`, while you pass a property called `text` inside your `index.html`. Therefore, the button doesn't get any text and then it's rendered without any inner content (and therefore slim, since you didn't give it fixed width and height).
You need to change the part of index.html and replace `text` with `button-label` (Vue automatically maps `buttonLabel` to it, and it is the better option. Using `buttonLabel` might not work in this case, since you are not using single file components.

Comment: What is the difference between 
    buttonLabel = 'blabla'
 and 
button-label = 'blabla'

Exept that first one not workning...

Comment: The capitalization. HTML is case-insensitive, so basically `buttonLabel` and `buttonlabel` are the same. However, Vue is case-sensitive. In order to support having capital letters in props, Vue automatically maps it to `button-label`. Single file components (.vue files) allow you to use `buttonLabel` inside the component as well, since they are compiled into js

Answer (score 0):

Call it like
`<mybutton mylabel="hI"></mybutton>`

```
Vue.component('mybutton', {
  props: ['mylabel'],
  template: '<button>{{ mylabel }}</button>'
})
```

https://codepen.io/flakerimi/pen/wvgGqVb

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html